# Environment variables in database vs application settings in Azure

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have a boss that is a bit old school (still uses Hungarian notation, e.g. oDatabaseContext) and insists that environment variables (not connection strings) should be pulled from the database instead of application settings in Azure.

Little more background:

- .NET Core 5
- Services are hosted on Azure
  Getting current settings is done in the following way
- Makes a database call to a separate database that holds all application settings where applicationId = x
  o   Loops through the returned records, with an expected number of settings.
  o   If the number of settings that comes back doesn't come back with the expected value, an exception is thrown
  o   Uses case statement with string literals to match the name of the setting
  o   Sets the value to a global variable

My opinion would be to set these variables in the Application Settings in for the app service in Azure.

Here's what I see, but not limited to, the pros and cons of each approach:

Database for settings:

Pros:

- Easier to find settings for all applications
- Can change application settings much faster
- Can be more easily create a UI to see the settings

Cons:

- Code bloat
- Tied to the database and not easily portable
- Since variables for all applications in there, easier to make a mistake and change a wrong setting
- Doesn't all for Options Patter
- There may be dozens of applications with their own settings

Application setting

Pros:

- Easily portable
- Specific to each service
- Better security
- Allows for Options Pattern

Cons:

- More difficult to navigate to each services settings

Looking for other options on the database settings approach.

Comment: *I have a boss* - and therein lies the root of the problem. It might be easier to fix which boss you have than fix the current boss you have. Your boss may have said "if you can get me 10 good reasons I agree with then I'll change my ways but, alas, SO is not for answered-with-a-list style questions like "tell me 10 uses for an old sock".

Comment: I disagree with all the Pros of the database approach btw; portal.azure.com embodies all those Pros - app settings go with each app, they can be changed right there and the UI is already built by Microsoft

Comment: Maybe you can convince him to use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/overview. Anyway, what reason does your boss have to want you to use the database?

Comment: @CaiusJard I was just trying to throw my boss a bone by listing out what he would say

Comment: LOL, yea, but I think that would make arguing your case harder. If you had to find 10 good reasons before, you'll have to find 13 if you give him 3 freebies! :D

Comment: @PeterBons . usually that would be the _we-always-did-it-that-way_ reason, wouldn't it :)